# can't upgrade from 9.04

Tags: upgrade

I just got ubuntu from my uncle and it is a older version 9.04 and I know to upgrade ubuntu it has to be in stages and I can't upgrade to 9.10 I always get fetch to fail error message saying can't connect to server...are there any solutions?

Comment: Back up your personal data then do a clean install.  I'm guessing as you have 9.04 that this is an old PCs so Ubuntu 13.10 may not run very well for you.  You can try it from USB or DVD without installing; If it runs fine install, if not try [Xubuntu](http://xubuntu.org/getxubuntu/) or [Lubuntu](http://www.lubuntu.net/) which are also supported here and will run on older hardware.

Answer (score 0):

You may as well just download 12.04 or 13.10 directly. Upgrading from such an old version would be ridiculous. It would use less of your bandwidth if you just downloaded the version you want, and your installation would be a lot more stable with a clean install.

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet is to make a clean install of either Ubuntu 12.04(Long Term Support) or 13.10(latest stable) otherwise you would need to upgrade from 9.04 to 9.10, 10.04 and from this you can jump to 12.04 since both are LTS releases.

If you still insist to upgrade thru all versions then you will have to follow all the instructions here:

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EOLUpgrades

If you choose to make a clean install this can be an opportunity to make a separate partition for /home/ so if a future upgrade goes wrong or you just simply want to try a new ubuntu release and avoid going thru update or even anoher linux distro you can easily keep your data.

http://www.psychocats.net/ubuntu/installseparatehome